# JSCOMPILER_PRESERVE after compiling javascript with KJSCompiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

After compiling my JavaScript source with KJSCompiler (https://github.com/knyga/kjscompiler) I get this weird function wrapped around my code. If I try to include it in my live source code I get this error in the console "Uncaught ReferenceError: JSCOMPILER_PRESERVE is not defined ".

I thought that this problem occurred because I didn't add the "wrapper" in the JSON file of kjscompiler. After trying that it still occurs.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this when using Closure Compiler directly via the Java API.

It seems to be caused by running the compiler in checks-only mode but with protect hidden side effects enabled. The late pass to remove protection of hidden side effects is skipped in checks-only mode.

I'm not sure about KJSCompiler specifically, but it might help to look at changing the compilation level to SIMPLE or ADVANCED, and/or how you might be able to control what checks and optimisations run to KJSCompiler, e.g. turning off [`CompilerOptions.protectHiddenSideEffects`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/a24991e33fbf34e6ae0df1ecb662a5d6d7e6f918/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java#L971).

See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/1875

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Steve S's answer:
set protectHiddenSideEffects after setting optimization level, as options.setProtectHiddenSideEffects(false); didn't work for me for GCC version v20180204 if I set it before setting CompilationLevel.

```
    CompilationLevel.ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(compilerOptions);

    //To remove JSCOMPILER_PRESERVE error: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/1875
    compilerOptions.setProtectHiddenSideEffects(false);
```